# How to extend model in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model

```
class User

 def fname
    @fname
 end

 def fname=(str)
    @fname = str
 end

 def greeting
    "Hello #{@fname}"
 end

end
```

But I want to remove the `greeting` method to somewhere else so that my user model don't include the business logic. 
How should I achieved that?
I try to create a module(foo.rb) in lib but its not working. Should I include in User model?

**Updated Info:**
I updated my code

```
            module UserBusinessEntity
              def speak(sound)
                return "#{sound} is its sound"
              end

              def greeting
                "#{self.id} Hello, #{self.fname} #{self.lname} you are #{self.age} years old"
              end
            end


            class User < ActiveRecord::Base
                include UserBusinessEntity
            end
```

This works if both code in same file.`i.e. app/models/User.rb` 
But I want to move the `module UserBusinessEntity` code to `app/services/`

Do I have to add require at User Model. If so I added like `require UserBusinessEntity` But Its gives `uninitialized constant UserBusinessEntity`

Comment: Why include Ube? Should be include UserBusinessEntity

Comment: Its is `UserBusinessEntity`. Sorry for the typo. But problem still exist.
If I put the `UserBusinessEntity` in some other folder it gives error

Comment: Have you tried reloading the app?

Comment: I add `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` in `config/application.rb` and required in the model. It works but we are looking some thing else so that our business entity have the data entity within. By the way Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a module like this:

```
module Foo
  def greeting
    "Hello #{self.fname}"
  end
end
```

Then include the module in your User module:

```
class User
  include Foo
  # ...
end
```

Then you can call in a controller or a view

```
@user = User.new
@user.greeting
```

Comment: I create the module in lib as `foo.rb` and include into my `models/users.rb`
And at users controller I called `render plain: User.new.foo`
I am getting `NameError`

Comment: Foo is a module, not an attribute/method, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may use `greeting` to render in views or mailers. So this is a showcase of using presenter. A good [article](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/) is here.

Basically, defining a presenter will be:

**app/presenters/user_presenter.rb**

```
class UserPresenter < DelegateClass(User)
  def greeting
    "Hello #{fname}"
  end
end
```

There are many ways to define, the above is just basic, check out above article for detail.

Then, you can use it anywhere you want to:

```
@user = User.first
UserPresenter.new(user).greeting
```

Or even in a view

**example.html.erb**

```
<p><%= UserPresenter.new(user).greeting %><p>
```

Moreover, people may use [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to implement this, but with me that is not a good practice!